# How can I do GridView editable,without edit link

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I do GridView editable,without edit link. In other words, when i click on cell textbox, it automatically goes to the edit mode (without clicking on edit again)?I want to save data when clicked enter on each TextBox ASP.NET WEB application.

Comment: What about save? Is it automatically saved or there is rowwise save button.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean ASP.Net GridView? GridView sends javascript postback (__dopostback(...) navigate cursor to edit link and note in status bar) when edit link is clicked, to solve your problem you should send that postback in other js event